# How to hstack several sparse matrices (feature matrices)?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I have 3 sparse matrices:

```
In [39]:

mat1


Out[39]:
(1, 878049)
<1x878049 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 878048 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [37]:

mat2


Out[37]:
(1, 878049)
<1x878049 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 744315 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [35]:

mat3



Out[35]:
(1, 878049)
<1x878049 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 788618 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html), I read that it is possible to `hstack`, `vstack`, and `concatenate` them such type of matrices. So I tried to `hstack` them:

```
import numpy as np

matrix1 = np.hstack([[address_feature, dayweek_feature]]).T
matrix2 = np.vstack([[matrix1, pddis_feature]]).T


X = matrix2
```

However, the dimensions do not match:

```
In [41]:

X_combined_features.shape

Out[41]:

(2, 1)
```

Note that I am stacking such matrices since I would like to use them with a scikit-learn classification algorithm. Therefore, **How should I `hstack` a number of different sparse matrices?**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `sparse` versions of `vstack`.  As general rule you need to use sparse functions and methods, not the `numpy` ones with similar name.  `sparse` matrices are not subclasses of `numpy` `ndarray`.

But, your 3 three matrices do not look sparse.  They are 1x878049.  One has 878048 nonzero elements - that means just one 0 element.

So you could just as well turned them into dense arrays (with `.toarray()` or `.A`) and use `np.hstack` or `np.vstack`.

```
np.hstack([address_feature.A, dayweek_feature.A])
```

And don't use the double brackets.  All concatenate functions take a simple list or tuple of the arrays.   And that list can have more than 2 arrays

```
In [296]: A=sparse.csr_matrix([0,1,2,0,0,1])

In [297]: B=sparse.csr_matrix([0,0,0,1,0,1])

In [298]: C=sparse.csr_matrix([1,0,0,0,1,0])

In [299]: sparse.vstack([A,B,C])
Out[299]: 
<3x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [300]: sparse.vstack([A,B,C]).A
Out[300]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)

In [301]: sparse.hstack([A,B,C]).A
Out[301]: array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)

In [302]: np.vstack([A.A,B.A,C.A])
Out[302]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, great answer!.